# ant db2 backup is not made sequential

Tags: ant, db2

I have the following ant code :

```
<parallel>
    <sequential>
        <mkdir dir="${DB2BACKUP}/DB2BACKUP"/>
        <exec executable="db2cmd">
            <arg value="DB2 BACKUP DATABASE DB TO C:\DB2BACKUP\ WITH 2 BUFFERS BUFFER 1024 PARALLELISM 1"/>
        </exec>
        <echo> hello </echo>
    </sequential>
</parallel>
```

when this gets executed, the directory gets created, another command line is opened where the db2 backup is running, but the ant is finishing up with "hello" echo immediately and doesn't wait for the db2 backup to complete. I tried with

```
<exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/C"/>
    <arg value="db2cw"/>
    <arg value="DB2 BACKUP DATABASE DB TO C:\DB2BACKUP\ WITH 2 BUFFERS BUFFER 1024 PARALLELISM 1"/>
</exec>
```

but it's the same, I think the main cause is the fact that the db2cmd is opening under a separate cmd line window. I tried also using the exec with spawn property on false (which is default I think either way) but still no luck, any thoughts ?

Comment: seems like /W flag made the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If the DB2 utilities are in PATH, you are running the commands as user that has enough priviledges, and you set the DB2INSTANCE environment valuable correctly you should not require db2cmd or any other intermediate command. You can just simply run the actual backup command.

Also I might want to point out that any active connection to your database will prevent the command from running in any case. Probably you might want to add "force application all" or "quiesce database" before your backup command. (Also remember to unquiesce if you go that route.)

Comment: yes, that quiesce/unquiesce is needed of course, I was able to have is solved using /W. Thanks